# Why default style of asp.net core is like this

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-core

```css
a.navbar-brand {
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: center;
    word-break: break-all;
}

/* Provide sufficient contrast against white background */
a {
    color: #0366d6;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b6ec2;
    border-color: #1861ac;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b6ec2;
    border-color: #1861ac;
}

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
    font-size: 14px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

.border-top {
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.box-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

button.accept-policy {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: inherit;
}

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
}
```

I'm coding on asp.net core and I just realized that the top navbar of _layout.cshtml isn't on top of the , Then I opened a new project to find out why it's behaving like that. then I found out that when I add code in Body of _layout page it'll float on left side of screen and it hurt the actuall template , Could you guys help me to put the navbar on top of the page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - PadshahOnlineShop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/Bootstrap-rtl.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">PadshahOnlineShop</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - PadshahOnlineShop - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvPtS.jpg)

Comment: Looks like your body tag somewhere got display: flex applied to it. I would try to find this and remove that style if needed.

Comment: Your `_Layout.cshtml` looks fine , Does this problem occur on all pages or only one ? Have you set the css style in the view page ？can you show your page code ?

Comment: @XinranShen Yes It shows in all of the pages in this position, I haven't edited default settings yet but I have download some css and html free templates and installed on them,I'll try to share the css code here :) thanks for your attention

Comment: @Gecko Thank you so much for your help , yes It's right , my style.css file somewhere got display:flex , I just removed it and now it works pretty well ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the css code you shared I find this:

```
.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
}
```

`display: flex`  may affect the top navbar of `_layout.cshtml` , you can try to remove it to see if it works fine.